# How to download POST Response file using selenium

Tags: java, html, selenium, pdf, post

My application will download a file when clicking on a button.
The file will download POST submit and there is no way to get the URL of the file before submitting it.

I am looking for a way to download POST request attachment using selenium. Can someone guide me on how to achieve this using selenium Java?.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain of your exact use case, but would something like this work? I made this example to download the Google Chrome.exe automatically. Like with your file, there is no direct link to it either but rather just a download generated by the website.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","where your ChromeDriver lives");
        Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        prefs.put("download.default_directory", "where you want the file to be downloaded");
        prefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", false);
        options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        String baseUrl = "https://www.google.com/chrome/";
        driver.get(baseUrl);
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
        } catch(Exception e){

        }
        List<WebElement> targetsWithClass = driver.findElements(By.className("chr-cta__button--blue"));
        targetsWithClass.get(1).click();
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
        } catch(Exception e){

        }
        driver.findElement(By.id("js-accept-install")).click();
    }

}
```